# How to use SQLDriverConnect from f#

Tags: f#, odbc, pinvoke

I am porting a VB.NET application to F# as an experiment.  The VB program uses SQLDriverConnect, so I need to call it from F#.  I cannot get the pinvoke/extern declaration to work properly.  The call to SQLDriver connect always returns -2, SQL_INVALID_HANDLE, instead of prompting for a connection as expected.

Anybody know how to get this to work?

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Text

[<DllImport("odbc32.dll")>]
extern Int16 SQLAllocEnv(IntPtr& EnvironmentHandle);

[<DllImport("odbc32.dll")>]
extern Int16 SQLDriverConnect(IntPtr hdbc, IntPtr hwnd, string szConnStrIn,
                              Int16 cbConnStrIn, StringBuilder szConnStrOut,
                              Int16 cbConnStrOutMax, Int16& pcbConnStrOut,
                              UInt16 fDriverCompletion)

let getConnectionString () =
    let SQL_DRIVER_PROMPT = 2us
    let mutable henv = IntPtr(0)
    let mutable csLen = 0s
    let rc1 = SQLAllocEnv &henv
    assert (rc1 = 0s)
    let csOut = new StringBuilder(1024)
    let rc2 = SQLDriverConnect(henv, IntPtr.Zero, "", 0s, csOut, 1024s, &csLen,     SQL_DRIVER_PROMPT)
    assert (rc2 = 0s)
    csOut.ToString()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "Connection string: %s" (getConnectionString())
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't do F# but in C you call SQLAllocEnv (or SQLAllocHandle) to create an environment handle, then you call SQLSetEnvAttr to set the version of ODBC you want, then SQLAllocConnect (or SQLAllocHandle) to allocate a connection handle and lastly call SQLDriverConnect with the connection handle. Your code looks to be passing an environment handle to SQLDriverConnect but SQLDriverConnect needs a connection handle hence SQL_INVALID_HANDLE.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem.  I can use the .NET ODBC classes once I have the connection string.

Comment: Then would you mind marking my answer correct please - UPDATE: oops, you have - sorry.